# How to create proper ViewModel for a complex Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a model that looks like this:

```cs
// Subclass 1
class A
  {
      public B PropB { get; set; }  
  }

// Subclass 2
class B
  {
      public List<A> PropA { get; set; }
  }

// And finally Model
class Model
  {
      public List<A> PropA { get; set; }
      public List<B> PropB { get; set; }
  }
```

Lists A and B inside Model class have references to **some** elements of each other.

How should the proper ViewModel look like in this case?

If there were no cross-references, that would be just 2 ObservableCollections of sub-ViewModels, but I cannot manage the situation with the references. Should each sub-ViewModel contain a  references to other sub-ViewModels?

Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: The ViewModel depends on what you want to show to the user. It doesn't have to have the exact same structure as your model.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I need to be able to find related ViewModels, so I don't understand how to organise that relation. As Model doesn't know anything about it's ViewModel, I cannot use Model's references directly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com). It allows you to lazy-load view models based on a model. This way, you can create endless chains of view models without having to specify them first.

So, when a view detects a specific model, it will automatically convert it into a view model and you are good to go. For more information, read the docs about the [nested user controls problem](http://catel.catenalogic.com/index.htm?gs_viewscontrols_nested_user_controls_problem.htm).

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of Catel